Fetch windows 11 cpu temperature in python 3.9.0 without admin priviledges
I am trying to get cpu temperature (mean value of all proccessors), using python 3.9.0 on windows 11 without admin priviledges.
Please answer full code that it's tested and works!
If you have a cmd command without need of admin run please also post.
